# MySQL-Store float in a varchar field and can't find?

Tags: mysql, sql

I store some float numbers format like 1.30 in a varchar field named height, and then I want to find data by height, so I was using

```
select * from table where height = '1.30'
```

to query. But nothing returned. And then I figured maybe I should query with float, so I changed the SQL into

```
select * from table where height = 1.30
```

and got the right result.

How could this happen? I mean, what happened when store that float in a varchar field.

Comment: "I store some float numbers format like 1.30 in a varchar field" - why?

Comment: i don't know why either,just did..

Comment: Maybe you actually stored `1.3000`. It's the same when treated as a float, but not as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your varchar column has some leading or trailing spaces. If you store decimal as varchar and put leading or trailing spaces, then your search criteria will never meet. so `' 1.30'` can not be equal to `'1.30'`.

However, if you compare it just `1.30`, then mysql first cast it and them compare. Hence you get the result. (This is what I think. Please correct me if I am wrong

**See the following example**

**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/503c2/1**

Comment: You are right,the column do have a leading space..thank you.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept it by clicking the `tick` symbol on left of the answer so it could be closed. Thanks